# PHP Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Tags: php, mysqli

I keep getting the error

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (usersName, usersEmail, usersUid, usersPwd) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("location: ../signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
    exit();
  }
  $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $name, $email, $username, $pwd, $hashedPwd);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
header("loctaion: ../signup.php?error=none");
}
```

Comment: I never see you assign to `$name`, `$email`, `$username`, or `$pwd`, which makes me wonder how you got `$hashedPwd`, but nevertheless, we don't see the variable assignment.

Comment: You are assigning 5 variables to 4 placeholders. I think you need to remove that `$pwd` from there.

Comment: @Dharman for the code present the error should be different I believe, "No data supplied for prepared statement". MEans clearly the code doesn't matc hthe error message

Answer (score 0):

The signature of [mysqli_stmt_bind_param()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) is `mysqli_stmt_bind_param(mysqli_stmt $stmt, string $types, mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ])`.

In general, you need 3 different things to match on this call:

- the number of `?` on your SQL statement (you have 4 in your `$sql`)
- the number of characters on your `$types` variable (you have 5 characters `s`)
- the number of variables passed after the 2 first parameters (you have 5: `$name, $email, $username, $pwd, $hashedPwd`)

Based on this, you either have to add a new parameter to your SQL query, or you need to remove one of the variables you are passing to your statement.